# Is there a spell checker for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, spell-checking

I'm looking for a simple spell checker to use with an text input. My application is being developed in ASP.NET MVC 2 within VS2010. I'm using the 4.0 version of the framework and my application will be accessed via an intranet using IE only.

A jQuery plugin would be ideal, but I'm happy to use any solution.

A step by step tutorial would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always keep in mind that no matter what technologies you are using for your backend (asp.net MVC) you are using HTML+CSS+Javascript in the client, so being said that, any spell checked that works with Javascript will be good for your project.

Several Javascript spell checked are available, pick the one that fits you the best:

- [jSpell](http://www.jspell.com/html-spell-checker.html?gclid=CNXVmdjZk6UCFate7AodUi8GNQ)
- [jQuery Spell checker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/)
- [jQuery Spell Checked plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellcheck)

Answer (score 3):

The •jQuery Spell checker is not pure client side code. It uses a PHP page. I know I wasted an evening with that one. It says it supports google but it still needs the php page to access google api.

•jQuery Spell Checked plug-in
Google has a limit of uses per day. And limits to ten words per query. If it is a small app then go for it.

I am checking out jspell now. It looks affordable and says it supports asp.net. Yes even that one is not pure client side. It uses a server side page.

Answer (score 3):

Self advertising: [http://forums.asp.net/t/1519923.aspx/1?Ajax+html+editor+spell+checker](http://forums.asp.net/t/1519923.aspx/1?Ajax%20html%20editor%20spell%20checker)

Check the last post, it's for MVC with Razor view engine and sample is implemented in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

The only javascript based solution i have found that doesn't require PHP was "JavaScript Spell Check" which offers a pure .net spellchecker which is MVC compatible.
http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com

ASPNetSpell also offer a pure .net component which is MVC compatible.
http://www.aspnetspell.com/MVCInstallation

*full disclosure* I have worked as a developer on both projects.  Of the 2 i like javascriptspellcheck because it works on many of different project types on Unix and also Win hosting.

Comment: http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com worked great.  For ASP.net MVC need to be installed in the /Contents folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the links on this page are to spell checkers that don't use .NET on the back-end.  I know RapidSpell is JavaScript based (so compatible with MVC) but also uses .NET on the server.

https://keyoti.com/products/rapidspell/dotNetWeb/spell-checker.html