# Reliable grammar and spell checker for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of a non-free spell checker and grammar check component?

I say non-free because we need one that is robust and really works with support.
Jquery's is not up to par for .net because it requires a PHP page. Doesn't do grammar anyway.

JSpell works pretty good and the price is right but does not do grammar.

Telerik you have to buy the entire suite of their tools and theirs does not do grammar.

Karamasoft has one and is affordable but requires using MS Word on the server and is not recommended for a website unless only a few people will using the site spell checker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a spell checker for ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810962/is-there-a-spell-checker-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: [checkspelling.php](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/source/browse/trunk/checkspelling.php) looks reasonably easy to re-code in .NET, for the Google case at least.

Comment: There is no such thing. Even the ones in professional high-profile enterprisey word processors subject to countless hours of development and decades of testing aren't very reliable.

Comment: Tell your users to use Google Chrome as their browser (spell checker built in) :).

Comment: @CheckRaise I really wish I could downvote that comment.

Comment: @rangitatanz if you used Chrome, you could!

Answer (score 2):

Check out RapidSpell Web .NET. It has a slew of features and even contains some multilingual dictionaries:

**RapidSpell Web .NET v3.8.0:**
http://keyoti.com/products/rapidspell/dotNetWeb/index.html

Comment: Pretty Expensive (from my point of view), but works VERY well

Answer (score 0):

[Wintertree software has a reasonable spell checker](http://www.wintertree-software.com/index.html).