# Asp.Net MVC 2 model binding with ASPNetSpell textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I bind some data from my model into an ASPNetSpell textbox?

```
<ASPNetSpell:SpellTextBox ID="SpellTextBox1" runat="server">Some text to spell check</ASPNetSpell:SpellTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that it is server control and you can't use it in the ASP.NET MVC.

You can find out about some of the spell checkers for asp.net mvc project [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972777/spell-checker-for-my-asp-net-mvc-application) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810962/is-there-a-spell-checker-for-asp-net-mvc) or [there](http://forums.asp.net/t/1629017.aspx/1).

UPDATE: You catch me. It works. I checked official site not careful in previous time. Did you check in the "how to" samples?

[Getting Started with ASPNetSpell](http://aspnetspell.com/Getting_Started)

[ASPNetSpell & MVC](http://aspnetspell.com/MVCInstallation)

[ASPNetSpell and the .Net Razor Framework](http://aspnetspell.com/Razor)

Comment: it does work with MVC, I just can't get it to bind to a model property. Thanks for the other recommendations though!