# How to create spell checker control at ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, spell-checking

I need to create/use spell checker control inside web application which detects words mistakes and underline it(wrong word) with red line and when right click over the word it offers suggested correct words like `Microsoft word`.

I need this action to be done client side not server side as when the user writes inside text box the checker detects words automatically without pressing "Button" and go to server, also i need to include my dictionary not using the control dictionary.

I need explicit code implementing this functionality please.

I have googled this issue and didn't find explicit code just algorithms or server side codes.

Comment: You should add the language and ide in the `tags`. Not in question description !!! Also you might get idea from [Is there a spell checker for ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810962/is-there-a-spell-checker-for-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: "I need explicit code implementing this functionality please." Then hire a contractor.

Comment: This should not be in the C# section. If it is client side then tag it with something like Javascript

Comment: @ean5533: I don't need a contractor i need a polite man to help me not rudy one!!

Comment: @Tosin My question had been edited and the tags had been changed to the current one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of free SpellCheckers you can download like "JSPELL".
A google search for "Javascript based spellcheckers" will return some good ones.