# custom spell checker for asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement a spell checker to my text areas. I browsed but couldn't find a good super-light weight, plug and play kind of spell checker. Hence I am thinking of writing it myself.

Basically I just want to check the spellings entered in a text area with a word dictionary stored in a text file. If the word is spelled wrong, the word should be highlighted red and user should be able to right click and see the correct spelling options.

What wold I need to write something like this is ASP.NET MVC? Alternative suggestions are most welcome

Comment: May Be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810962/is-there-a-spell-checker-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself but you can try CKEditor spell checker. Below is the link:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck-section-the-native-spell-checker